# include source files using path in makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, include-path

I have one directory called MAKE and two sub directory's source and header. source contains cpp files and header contains one header file which is included in all three cpp files.
I am trying to create a make file.
i am trying to access the source and header files from the directories. my current directory is MAKE(where my make file is present).

I am getting error as NO rule to target. Stop
Where am i going wrong

```
    CC = g++
    INC_SOURCE = -I/home/abhiskekkumar/Desktop/VINEETH/Make/source/
    INC_DEST =  -I/home/abhiskekkumar/Desktop/VINEETH/Make/header
    SOURCE = $(shell echo *.cpp)
    HEADER = $(shell echo *.h)
    OBJECT = $(SOURCE:.cpp=.o)
    TARGET = output

    EXEC: $(TARGET)
            ./output
    $(TARGET): $(OBJECT)
            $(CC) $(INC_SOURCE) $(INC_DEST) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECT)
```

Comment: Well, for a start, what do expect `$(shell echo *.cpp)` will return in the Make directory? It will not scan subdirectories. The recommended way to handle project layouts like this is to use the `vpath` mechanism in GNU Make (which I assume you're using)

Comment: In case it's not clear, $(OBJECT) is almost certainly empty, unless you have cpp files in the Make directory.

Comment: i am not using vpath. i am a beginner. How do i need to modify SOURCE = $(shell echo *.cpp) & HEADER = $(shell echo *.h) if i am not going to use vpath ? And you are right. My makefile executes if my cpp files are in the make directory.

Comment: Where your source files are placed? Why do you need `HEADER` if you don't use it? What `INC_SOURCE` and `INC_DEST` meaning? Copy headers from one directory to another?.. There is no rule to do so, though.

Comment: Razor, you're performing a shell glob in the Make directory. If there are no cpp files int that dir, then $OBJECT will be empty. I'm trying to help you learn about Make, vpath is a better way of doing this. If you insist on your way, then either look up the documentation of the `find` command, which does look in subdirectories, or use something like `$(wildcard source/*.cpp)` etc. An hour reading the Make manual will save you a *lot* of pain, trust me!

Comment: I dont wanna learn in the hard way sir. Could you kindly modify the code with the usage of vpath and post it here. I am so desperate to see the output. Help me.

Comment: keltar, My source directory contains .cpp files and header directory contains one .h file which i include in all three cpp files. INC_SOURCE is the path to the source files and INC_HEAD is the path to that header file so that i can access these files. The reason why i did it is because i dont want to proactively mention the file names, but instead i want to use the path and fetch the files and execute it.

Comment: You don't wanna learn the hard way? You're *gonna* expend at least a little bit of effort in order to learn anything. I for one will walk you through this, if you're willing to walk and not be carried.

Comment: @Razor there is no `INC_HEAD` in your file, only `INC_DEST`, and this word commonly used as shortcut for 'destination', which makes no sense here. Furthermore, `INC` may only be read as 'include', which too makes no sense in case it points to sources. If goal of this makefile was to deceive whoever will read it - congrats, you got it. `$(wildcard source/*.cpp)` already mentioned, nothing left to say here.

Comment: @Beta I am willing to walk.. Kindly help me out. @ Razor, what do u suggest me to do? Can u help me modify the code in your way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 CC = g++
 TARGET = vineeth

 CFLAGS   = -Wall

 LINKER   = g++ -o


SRCDIR   = source
HEADDIR  = header
OBJDIR   = obj
BINDIR   = bin

SOURCES  := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
INCLUDES := $(wildcard $(HEADDIR)/*.h)
OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)


$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
     $(LINKER) $@ $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS)
     @echo "Linking complete!"

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
     @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
     @echo "Compiled "$<" successfully!"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** we write a makefile that does nothing, but does it correctly.

```
nothing:
    @:
```

**We must test this, and get it working perfectly before we proceed.**

**Step 2:** we generate a list of source files, and print it out so that we know that it's correct.

```
SOURCE = $(wildcard source/*.cpp)
$(info $(SOURCE))

nothing:
    @:
```

**We must test this, and get it working perfectly before we proceed.**

**Step 3:** we decide where we want the object files to go (e.g. `MAKE/`, `MAKE/source/`, or somewhere else).

Try this, post a comment with the results, and we'll proceed.

Comment: @Razor: ...and what about step 3? Did you actually do these things, or are you waiting for a full solution?

Comment: I went till step 10 or maybe 15 and arrived at the solution. I also did post my solution here. Have a look and share your comments.

Comment: Could you please share with me some important web pages so that i can study makefiles from the scratch and go on to some advance stuffs. Thank you ...

Comment: STEP 1: nothing:
            @:             Result-> Make: Nothing to be done for nothing. STEP 2) Result ->source/a.cpp source/b.cpp source/c.cpp Make: Nothing to be done for nothing. I didnt understand Step 3. Could you explain in details as in what exactly should i do?